# GitHub Branch Protection Disable Bypass

Tags: github, github-actions

Starting to setup branch protection rules for our Main branches and currently have the following options enabled:

- Require a pull request before merging

  - Require approvals = 1
- Require conversation resolution before merging

However I noticed in a PR there was an option to "Merge without waiting for requirements to be met (bypass branch protection)":

[image]

Is there a way to disable this option for all users? I did see an option for "Allow specified actors to bypass required pull requests", but is not really the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you an administrator for this repository ?

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski I am admin for the repo. I will run some tests and confirm if other users have that option or not. Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: then you need to check the "include administrators" option to force the limitation to everyone

Comment: Since Aug. 18th, 2002, you now have "[**Bypass branch protections with a new permission**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73410060/6309)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the branch protection rules, there's a setting "Include administrators". Make sure to enable that as well.

[image: include administrators screenshot]

More information can be found in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule).

Comment: Completely overlooked that option. Confirmed that enabling this option disables the bypass option for admins, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's still in branch protection rules as mentioned in the accepted answer above, but its worded slightly different now.
[image: Branch protection rules]